# Task / todo / outline system in Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, collaboration, google-tasks

In project planning, sometimes I do a todo / task list because I can create an outline with multiple levels. But then I want to share that task list with several people and either give them view or edit capabilities. Unfortunately I have yet to find a system on how to do this with Google Apps, now that my company switched over to that.

Does anyone know how to make a task / todo / outline system in Google Apps and then share that with teammates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are a Google Apps Reseller.

The two most successful tools we have seen our customers using are: shared Google Spreadsheets and Trello.

The spreadsheet might seem crude but it is very flexible in how you set it up, it can be sorted and comments can be inserted. This would be the quickest for you to start using right away. Depending on the complexity and quantity of the tasks, you might want to look at Google Apps Script for automating your work with the tasks in the spreadsheet.

Trello is a really cool app made by the same folks that built StackExchange. It does not integrate with Google Apps directly but you can use your Google login (nice to not have to remember another password). Additionally, if you want to get more complex, it has an API which can be manipulated with Google Apps Script.

We have seen both work successfully in Google Apps environments. Take a look at each to see if either will work for you.

Comment: Thx, I see you have made quite a reputation here Jacob!

Comment: I like Trello, and how it integrates with our Google Apps accounts and has org sharing and privacy. I wish Workflowy.com had that!

Answer (score 0):

netkiller docs. It enforce document ownership changes when submit a document and get approval.

https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=2333+15557384810033584025&category=&query=netkiller+docs

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the service you mentioned, otherwise your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is now a great, free, third-party solution for sharing/syncing Google Tasks. It's still in beta and not quite perfect yet, but gets the job done.

http://www.isynctasks.de/

A few notes:

- You can only provide edit permission, not view permission
- You don't have control over how often it syncs, but it's roughly every 15 minutes.
- It only syncs tasks that haven't been cleared (using "clear completed tasks" from the menu).
- If someone else checks off a task, it gets checked off on the other users' lists, but each user has to clear the completed tasks on their own list. This is by design so that each user will know the tasks were finished.

A huge thanks to [herr.kaste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526957/herr-kaste) for developing this!